# EF How to relate already loaded entities?

Tags: entity-framework-4, wcf-ria-services

I have the following methods on the server (RIA services):

```
public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomers()
{
    return ObjectContext.Customers;
}

public IQueryable<Customer> GetCustomersWithInvoicesAndInvoiceItemsAsync()
{
    return ObjectContext.Customers
        .Include("Invoices.InvoiceItems");
}
```

These items are loaded on client as IEnumerable<>, lets name the CollectionA and CollectionB. My problem is next: If I add/remove a Customer in CollectionA, CollectionB will not be aware of it. Editing is working as expected, since both of collections contain same entities. Is there a way I can load Invoices separately, and relate them in the client, so I would work only on one collection of customers, and not two?

Comment: If your Invoices have a CustomerId or the like you can fetch the invoices and join them with Customers.

Comment: Yes, this is my question - how? Will I get the same result as I have executed the second query?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Service-side (beside the GetCustomers method):

```
public IQueryable<Invoice> GetInvoicesAndInvoiceItemsAsync()
{
    return ObjectContext.Invoices.Include("InvoiceItems");
}
```

Client-side, after getting customers and invoices in separate calls (as `IEnumerable`s):

```
var query = customers.Join(invoices, c => c.CustomerId, i => i.CustomerId,
    (c,i) => Tuple.Create(c, i) );
```

This will give you a list of Customer - Invoice pairs. Or use GroupJoin:

```
var query = customers.GroupJoin(invoices, c => c.CustomerId, i => i.CustomerId,
    (c,i) => Tuple.Create(c, i) );
```

This will give you a list of Customer - Invoices (plural) pairs.

Comment: Hi GertArnold, sorry for late reponse, I was unable to try out your advice until today. The result is not the same as the one I was looking for. I am receiving a list of Tuple objects, while I needed to receive a list of customer objects, as I would in my 2nd example query

Comment: I understand, but then you'd have to change the `Customer`'s Invoices collection. You could `Add` the invoices to this collection, but I'd prefer not to tamper with a collection that is change-tracked by EF. Maybe you can add an unmapped invoices collection to the Customer class.

Comment: Collections on the client (ex List<T>) are not being change-tracked, only the entities inside the collection are being change tracked. The solution you have provided is wrapping a customer inside Tuple collection, so again will not have any connection to original customers collection. If I am to add a customer in original customer collection, Tuple collection will not know anything about it. Is there no way to to this other than manually adding items?